AcquireTokenInteractive does not show the login window in MSAL .NET
Currently our project uses a VSTO addin projects for Office Applications. On addin load, we are trying to make the authentication. The authentication code is in a class library project (on .NET 4.7.2).
I am using Word Vsto project. On opening the word application, and clicking on new document. Application_WindowActivate event will get triggered, inside this event, I am writing the logic for authentication:
void Application_WindowActivate(Interop.Document Doc, Interop.Window Wn)
{ 
    onDocOpen(Doc, Wn);
}

Inside the onDocOpen method, I am calling an object AuthenticateOffice which is a class library (.NET 4.7.2)
   AuthenticateOffice authResult = new AuthenticateOffice();

The above class has logic for fetching Azure ClientID, authority and I am using that in the below method for MSAL approach.
NOTE: This has been working without any issues on ADAL approach (using AuthenticationContext) login pop-up has been showing.
I have followed the documentation and added this code:
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read" };

var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
              .Create(ADFS_clientID)
              .WithAuthority(ADFS_authority)
              .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
              .Build();

var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

AuthenticationResult result = null;

try
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                      .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
{
    // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilent.
    // This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenInteractive to acquire a token
    Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

    try
    {
        result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                                   .WithParentOfficeAddin.GetActiveWindow())
                                   .ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (MsalException)
    {
        // ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
    }
}

return result;

The AcquireTokenInteractiveis not showing the login pop-up. Did I miss something here?
I do also using the WithParentActivityOrWindow but still nothing helped. Can someone please help this out?
Once AcquireTokenInteractive is successful, the sequential calls AcquireTokenSilent will be successful.

Is it hitting the exception? Perhaps AcquireTokenSilent is succeeding?

AcquireTokenSilent will throw exception and it will try to get token from Interactive approach. No exception, nothing. It simply doesnt do anything after AcquireTokenInteractive call. @RyanWilson

Is this wrapped in a library method? How is this being called and from where? Please add a little more context.

@RyanWilson included more details in the description please check, if u feel some more information required will update accordingly.

So you are calling async methods from inside a constructor that is called inside a void method?

yes! i also used .Wait() but not helping.

is there an async version of  Application_WindowActivate? Where the signature would be something like async Task Application_WindowActivate? Or perhaps even async void Application_WindowActivate

No. i cannot use async Task there. Few blogs recommending to use WAM(Web Authentication Manager) approach in this, is it really required?
